# Pass Values to ListView by Clicking a Button

Tags: android

I want to pass values to list view by clicking a button. Problem is I want to make a list by gaining values from different activities with several buttons.

> For Example : 
>   In `EnglandActivity` if I click Button **Visit** I want to pass "England" to **ListView** in `MainActivity`,
>   In MalaysiaActivity pass "Malaysia" to ListView in MainActivity.

I dont know how to do that, Can you help me??

Comment: use `Intent` to pass

Comment: you're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Of All, You should write this on your `onCreate()` method of *MainActivity.java*

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

String data;/*For Storing Country Name*/
ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView); /*Finding ListView From Layout*/
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); /*ArrayList To Store All The Data Of ListView*/
ArrayAdapter adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);/*Defining ArrayAdapter For ListView*/
listview.setAdapter(adapter); /*Setting Adapter To ListView*/
Bundle intentExtras = getIntent().getExtras(); /*Getting The Intent Extras Sent By The Activity Which You Had Navigated From*/
if(intentExtras != null) {/*Checking For Null*/
     data= intentExtras.getString("countryName");/*Extracting The Data From The Intent Extras*/
     list.add(0,data);/*You Can Replace 0 With The Position Of Your Wish*/
} else {
    data=null;
      }
}
```

Now Write This In The `OnClickListener()` Method Of Button On Each *CountryNameActivity.java*

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {/*Setting The Click Listener*/
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.this)/*Defining The Intent*/
       intent.putExtra("countryName","CountryName");/*Putting The Data To Pass To The Next Activity*/
       startActivity(intent);/*Starting The Activity*/
        }
    });
```

Comment: @HansiniLakshani Please Tick The Answer if It Works For You, Welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Make an object shared by all of your activity, put your data there and read them when you must put data into your `ListView`'s adapter

Comment: Thank u firegloves :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
        position, long id) {

            Intent listIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class); 
            listIntent.putExtra("country", yourList.get(position));
            startActivity(listIntent);
        }
    });
```

in next activity onCreate:

```
String country;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        country= null;
    } else {
        country= extras.getString("country");
    }
```

Comment: What OP want is pass values to list view

Comment: I did not get you, can you post your full code, so i can tell you way to pass your data to activity

Comment: This is to pass values to button. Isn't it?

Comment: No it is to pass data to next activity when list item is clicked.